# Convert a div in a Jsf page to PDF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I develop a JSF application and need to convert a div or some other container like h:panalGroup or p:panel to PDF. How can I print a container of the page to a PDF document.

Important: 
I can not print the whole page.
I can not use primefaces data exported as it renders only a databtable

Answer (score 2):

For my experience, there are two process.

1. Printing the content.
2. Install PDF Printer (Eg : doPDFv7)

Example Code

```
<p:commandButton value="Print">
    <p:printer target="printPanel" />
</p:commandButton>
<h:panelGroup id="printPanel">
    here you print content
</h:panelGroup>
```

Make sure the printer Setting in Browser(Firefox) as below.
[image]

When you click `Print` buttom, `Print` dialog will be appere. Choose `PDF` printer and print it.

[image]

Your content will be print as PDF File.

Comment: For the moment, we are using this method. But the users are so demanding they want just one button to download the pdf with details like name and test in the pdf file name.

Comment: another solution is, Reporting API like `JasperReprot`. Try to display with primefaces. But, I will not directly convert `div` content to jasper report.